# What is a word for "known incorrectly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to organise a series of items, depending on whether these are known, unknown or known incorrectly to the observer.

I don't like the "know incorrectly" formulation. Is there a single word describing this?

PS: it seems the question was unclear. I am referring here to "known" as in "recognised". So I am categorising the objects as "recognised", "unrecognised" or "incorrectly recognised". (eg. you see the Eiffel Tower and shout "Look! The Bamiyan Buddha is still standing!")

Comment: Can you give an example of "knowing incorrectly" - is it identifying an item wrong (by mistake), or telling a lie about the item or soemthing else?

Comment: I mean "something that the observer believes to know, but recognised wrongly".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[***misidentify***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misidentify):

> To mistake the identity.

[***misrecognize***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misrecognize):

> 1. (psychology, computing) To recognize in error
>    This process of misrecognizing one's self in the image in the mirror creates the ego, the entity that says 'I.'
> 2. (sociology) To deliberately fail to recognize, or pretend to do so
>    When people did participate in blat practice, they misrecognized their actions through narratives of friendship.

Comment: I like this! :)

Answer (score 7):

How about *[misrecognized](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misrecognized)* from

> **[misrecognize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misrecognize)** (Wiktionary)
>
> 1. (psychology, computing) To recognize in error.
> 2. (sociology) To deliberately fail to recognize, or pretend to do so.
>
> **[misrecognize](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misrecognize)** (Oxford)
>
> 1. mistake the identity of.

or *[misidentified](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misidentified)* from

> **[misidentify](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misidentify)** (Wiktionary)
>
> 1. To mistake the identity.
>
> **[misidentify](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misidentify)** (Oxford)
>
> 1. identify (something or someone) incorrectly.

Comment: Note to self: press [Save] immediately after having a draft answer, do formatting afterwards :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for *[misunderstanding](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misunderstanding)*:

> **mis·un·der·stand·ing**  (msn-dr-stndng)
>   *n.*
>   1. A failure to understand or interpret correctly.

Synonyms are *misapprehension* and *mistake*.

Comment: I doubt it can be said of an object that it is "misunderstood" if its observer fails to recognise it.

Comment: @Benjamin: Sure it can, as perhaps you misunderstood my answer as failing to apply to the situation you describe. Or I may have misunderstood your question. Either way, what we appear to have now is a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

[***misconception***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misconception):

> a mistaken belief, a wrong idea
>
> ```
> There are several common misconceptions about the theory of relativity.
> You're obviously under the misconception that I care about your problems.
> ```

Comment: I think the word would not apply to my situation. Objects are shown on pictures and are not recognised as what they are but mistaken for something else. I sense that misconception would be the same situation, but without the pictures, ie. on a conceptual level only. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

> **misknow** *(v. t.)*:
>
> To have a misconception of
>   *or*
>   To have a mistaken notion of or about.

You can use **misknown** or **misinterpreted**.

Comment: I didn't know miskown existed. It comes handy :)

Comment: @Benjamin: even though this exists in a dictionary, this is pretty rare (do a [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/) on it and pretty much any other word), and pretty opaque to a modern listener (myself).